# poner valor de input en un div cuando cambie su valor

Tags: javascript, html, funciones

hacer un formulario que llame una funcion cada vez que haya un cambio en el input

```
     function cambio(){
     var cambio=document.getElementById("nombre").value;
     document.getElementById("valor_nombre").innerHTML=cambio;
     }
```

html

```
     <form action="" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="nombre" id="nombre">
    <div id="valor_nombre"> </div>

    </form>
```

Lo que deseo es que se llame la función cambio cuando en el input se agrege o se elimine un caracter, y la función lo que hará será copiar el valor del input y pegarlo en el div.

¿Que le debo poner al input?

Comment: como puedo hacer para que cuando haga un cambio en el valor de el input llame a la funcion cambio

Comment: lo que deseo es que el se llame la funcion cambio cuando el input se agrege o se elimine un caracter, y la funcion lo que ara sera copiar el valor del input y pegarlo en el div

Answer (score 2):

Todos los elementos HTML tienen eventos. Y a cada elemento se le puede asignar una función que se llama cuando se dispara el evento. En este caso, te interesa el evento `input`.

De https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event:

> El evento `input` se dispara cuando el valor (value) de un elemento `<input>`, `<select>`, o `<textarea>` ha sido cambiado.

```js
const elemNombre = document.getElementById("nombre"),
      elemValorNombre = document.getElementById("valor_nombre");

function cambio(evento) {
  var cambio = elemNombre.value;   //también podrías usar  evento.target.value
  elemValorNombre.innerText = cambio;
}


//Acá se asocia el evento con la funcion cambio()
elemNombre.addEventListener('input', cambio);
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="nombre" id="nombre">
  <div id="valor_nombre"> </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Tu código *funciona* salvo los siguientes puntos:

- No invocas a la función
- No le indicas a JS en que evento debe ejecutar esta función
- Puedes:

  - Invocar inline a la función dentro de la etiqueta HTML, asociando esta llamado al evento `onkeyup`
  - O recuperar el input por medio de su id y darle un listener al mismo evento pero aqui sería: `keyup`

Código:

```html
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="nombre" onkeyup="cambio()" placeholder="nombre" id="nombre">
<div id="valor_nombre"> 

</div>
</form> 

<script>
    function cambio () {
        let cambio=document.getElementById("nombre").value;
        document.getElementById("valor_nombre").innerHTML = cambio;
    }
</script>
```

Para no involucrar el llamado de la función directo en el HTML, podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```html
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="nombre" id="nombre">
        <div id="valor_nombre"> 
    
        </div>
    </form> 
        
        <script>
          
          let valorOriginal = document.getElementById('nombre');
          let valorClonado  = document.getElementById("valor_nombre");
          
          valorOriginal.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
            valorClonado.innerText = valorOriginal.value;
          })
        </script>
```

**Referencia**

- [Evento keyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/keyup_event)
- [eventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)